# In v2.0 of Mailchimp API Integration in PHP, FNAME and LNAME not passing with batchSubscribe() with grouping

Tags: php, mailchimp

It works fine. The groups are created. Emails are subscribed to these groups. But i can't insert the firstname and last name along with it.

```
foreach($email as $batches){ 

 $fname=$Subscriber['subscriber_firstname'];
 $lname=$Subscriber['subscriber_lastname'];

 $merge_vars =array(
      'fname'=>$fname,         
       'lname'=>$lname,      
      'groupings'=>array(
                    array('id' =>$group_id, 
                         'groups' =>array($group_name)
                          )
                        )
                );   

 $batch[] = array('email'=>array('email' =>$batches), $merge_vars);

 }
$subscriber = $Mailchimp_Lists -> batchSubscribe($listid,$batch, false, true, true);
print_r($batch);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found that the documentation on mailchimp is wrong, you need to literally supply the array element 'MERGE_VARS'.

```
$batch[] = array(
  'EMAIL'      => array('email' => 'address@example.com'),
  'MERGE_VARS' => array(
    'FNAME' => 'First Name',
    'LNAME' => 'Last Name'
  )
);
```